# Replacing NA in for/if loop in R

Tags: r

I'm running into an unexpected challenge in R. In my dataset, there are NA in certain columns. Some of these NAs SHOULD be present (the values are truly missing), while others should be replaced with 0s. I used code like the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c(10, 10, NA, NA, 12), z = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9))
for (i in nrow(df1)){
  if(df1$x[i] > 3){
    df1$y[i] = 0
    df1$z[i] = 0
  }
}
```

And obtained this output

```
  x  y z
1 1 10 9
2 2 10 9
3 3 NA 9
4 4 NA 9
5 5  0 0
```

The NA SHOULD be preserved in row 3, but the NA in row 4 should have been replaced with 0. Further, the z value in row 4 did not update. Any ideas as to what is happening?

Comment: I don't know how large your real dataset is, but note you might find the `replace()` function helpful for this task, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used `for i in nrow(df1)` which evaluates to `for i in 5`. I'm guessing you meant to use `for i in 1:nrow(df1)`, which would evaluate to `for i in 1:5` and include all rows.

Comment: Ah, you're exactly right! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it this way, R isn't Python, you get your vectorized functions out of the box:

```
df1[df1$x > 3, c('y', 'z')] <- 0

df1

#   x  y z
# 1 1 10 9
# 2 2 10 9
# 3 3 NA 9
# 4 4  0 0
# 5 5  0 0
```